# Cannot set div top attribute

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to change the top value of a div from Javascript, but for some reason it's not working and just sticks with the CSS value. So in this test I try and change it to 500, but it stays at 50. Whatever value I change in CSS will reflect in the position no matter what value I try and over-ride it with in Javascript. If I remove the top from CSS, the value will be 0 no matter what.

Am I missing something obvious here?

```
var tQuestItemContainer = document.createElement('div');
tQuestItemContainer.id = 'popup_quests_item_container';
tQuestItemContainer.top = 500 + "px";
alert('top: ' + tQuestItemContainer.top);
tQuestContainer.appendChild(tQuestItemContainer);
```

Here's the CSS

```
 #popup_quests_item_container{
  position: absolute;
    width: 320px;
    height: 30px;
    top:50px;
    left:13px;
    background-color: #000000;
    border: 1px solid #676669;
    cursor: pointer;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the style attribute:

```
tQuestItemContainer.style.top = 500 + "px";
```